# RPi 2 - size between screw holes

Tags: hardware

I was googling for a while, but i did not found anything relevant. So, I'm asking here: "What's the size between screw holes on Raspberry Pi 2?"

Comment: That's a good question - and as someone looking to include a RPi in a bigger case with other things for a particular project one that I would have had to have asked at some stage...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the mechanical drawing for Model 1, B+ (which, as I understand, is the same footprint as the Pi2).

It is from the Official Foundation document [Raspberry-Pi-B-Plus-V1.2-Mechanical-Drawing](https://web.archive.org/web/20170421105708/https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/mechanical/Raspberry-Pi-B-Plus-V1.2-Mechanical-Drawing.pdf):
[image]

Comment: @SlySven - thanks for the suggested edits. I'm still finding my way around using the various functions available when posting.

Comment: That's OK - it may be that you would not have had sufficient  reputation to include the image anyhow.  That should soon get better...!